# Como pegar uma versão específica de uma biblioteca via NuGet?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Eu preciso utilizar uma biblioteca com uma versão específica, em um projeto antigo. Lembro de já ter baixado uma vez outra biblioteca pelo console do NuGet especificando a versão, mas não me recordo e nem sei se existe um padrão para isso e se qualquer pacote o NuGet disponibiliza versões antigas.

Nesse caso seria o iTextSharp 4.1.2.0

Existe um padrão? Como ficaria?

```
PM> Install-Package iTextSharp ???Versão???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o parâmetro `Version`:

```
Install-Package iTextSharp -Version 4.1.2.0
```